# How can I programmatically determine if a stored procedure selects from another database?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

On an MS SQL Server 2000 installation I have numerous stored procedures that pull data from databases other than the one it's stored in. All selects occur on the same database server. For example:

```
select * from [OtherDatabase]..table
```

How can I find which procedures do that sort of thing without eyeballing each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a stored proc that will search for text contained in any stored proc. You could use this to search for the various databases that might get called.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindTextInSP
@StringToSearch varchar(100) 
AS 
   SET @StringToSearch = '%' +@StringToSearch + '%'
   SELECT Distinct SO.Name
   FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
   AND SO.Type = 'P'
   AND SC.Text LIKE @stringtosearch
   ORDER BY SO.Name
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. And if I replace 'P' with 'V' that should work for views?

Comment: This will find any sprocs where "TargetDB" is _explicitly_ referenced, but it won't find cases where a sproc dynamically determines a DB name (perhaps by calling some query) and then executes dynamic SQL using spexec(). That's a nit pick though, and I'm not sure _any_ solution exists that will do that...

Comment: That's either EXEC() or sp_ExecuteSQL. Never came across spexec(). :-)

Comment: @Seth Petry-Johnson, Okay, but it's an edge case I'm willing to ignore for the moment. :) But if I had to find which procedures were executing dynamic SQL would it be enough to include '%spexec%' as @StringToSearch?

Comment: No, you won't find sp_executeSQL because of the missing underscore. Either run the procedure twice with different arguments or add a second (third....) parameter to the procedure to make it look like something like this:

SELECT Distinct SO.Name
FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
WHERE SO.Type = 'P' AND 
SC.Text LIKE @stringtosearch OR 
SC.Text LIKE @stringtosearch2
ORDER BY SO.Name

EDIT: Sorry, can't figure out how to format the code better...

Answer (score 1):

Would this code do...You would need to temporarily connect to the database on the other server? You would need to be a member of the 'sysadmin' group for this to work...top off my head....it may be wrong, feel free to point this out...

```
USE MASTER
GO

sp_addserver @server='AnotherSQLServer'
USE [AnotherSQLServer].Master
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM [AnotherSQLServer].sysobjects WHERE name = 'some_proc' AND type = 'P') 
THEN
    ' DO WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO
    'DROP PROCEDURE some_proc
END
GO

USE MASTER
GO

sp_dropserver @server='AnotherSQLServer'
```

Comment: I don't need to access a database on a different server, but thanks.

Comment: @Jonathon: I misunderstood when you said "pull data from databases other than the one it's stored in" and "find which procedures do that sort of thing without eyeballing each one", in other words, I thought you meant to find out the sprocs on another database residing on another server...but no problem! Glad to help you anyway! :)

Comment: That's cool. :) Mentioning that everything is on the same server had crossed my mind. I've clarified the question now.